# How to convert a sum of money to Indian currency format(Indian number format)?

Tags: c

I wanted to build a C program to convert any number to Indian Currency Format. It can take inputs with negative sign, leading zeros and Decimal point + Mantissa and it will format the input to take care of the leading zeros and add the commas according to Indian number foramt. For example, numbers in Indian Number Format are represented as:

```
1
10 
100 
1,000 
10,000 
1,00,000 
10,00,000 
1,00,00,000 
10,00,00,000
```

the input and related output would be like:

```
Minus sign: "-12345" -> "-12,345"
Decimal Point: "-12345.123" -> "-12,345.123"
Leading Zero's: 000000.123 → "0.123" or "-000123456.1234" -> "-1,23,456.1234"
```

If anyone would like to optimise this code in terms of time and space complexity, make it more concise and clean then do share your code.

Comment: This is not a question. Also, stackoverflow is not a place to share code.

Comment: He has asked for optimization.

Comment: If the question is how to optimize the posted code (in terms of... what?), it should be in the question. And possibly https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better fit in that case.

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius I thought it was encouraged to ask and answer your own question, according to this post "https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/". That's why I posted an answer to my own question. I clicked on the "Answer your own question checkbox". Did I do something wrong. I meant optimise in terms of space and time complexity.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius The title is the question.  Explicit `?` added.  Post could be improved though.

Comment: @TobySpeight I have given my code as an answer. This post was never meant to be a question, I wanted to share my code so it may be of some use to someone else. I thought it was encouraged to do so on Stackoverflow based on this- https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: The usual means of such locale-specific formatting is `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "en_IN")` or similar.  You can demonstrate in shell
with `LC_NUMERIC=en_GB printf "%'d\n" 2250000`
(which prints `2,250,000`) 
and with `LC_NUMERIC=en_IN printf "%'d\n" 2250000`
(which prints `22,50,000`).  No need to write extra code.

Comment: The question quality guidelines still apply to self-answered Q&A: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340888/4076315

Answer (score 2):

Indian numbers are represented in decimal with groups of digits separated by commas. The last group has 3 digits and all more significant digits are grouped in pairs.

Here is a simple solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *convertToInrFormat(const char *s) {
    const char *src = s + strspn(s, " \t\r\n");  /* skip spaces */
    int len = strspn(src, "0123456789");   /* count number of digits */
    int destlen = len + (len > 3 ? len / 2 - 1 : len == 0);
    char *dest = malloc(destlen + 1);
    if (dest != NULL) {
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        while (i < len) {
            dest[j++] = src[i++];
            if (i + 2 < len && ((i ^ len) & 1))
                dest[j++] = ',';
        }
        if (len == 0) {
            dest[j++] = '0';
        }
        dest[j] = '\0';
    }
    return dest;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        char *input = argv[i];
        char *output = convertToInrFormat(input);
        printf("%s -> %s\n", input, output);
        free(output);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your code, just one thing the mallock's void pointer needs to be typecasted to a char pointer. Also, any particular reason you are sending the data to the function 1 character at a time?

Comment: @user258365: In C, the `void*` pointer returned by `malloc()` does not need to be typecasted, and this cast is considered bad style by many C programmers. If your compiler complains about the missing cast, it is probably compiling the code as C++, where the cast is indeed required.  C and C++ are different languages with subtile differences in their common subset. I am not sending the data to the function one character at a time, I am calling the function and printing the conversion for all arguments from the command line.

Comment: could you explain why you did "len == 0" in the ternary part of the Destlen calculation.

Comment: The purpose of the test `len == 0` is to ensure the destination string has at least space for the digit `0` if the amount is not given in the source string. If you want the conversion function to return en empty string in case there is no number in the source string, change the test to `0` and remove the `if (len == 0) { dest[j++] = '0'; }` statement.

Comment: Can I ask how does a programmer develop the skills to write stuff like this:- ((i ^ len) & 1). I understand how the Bitwise operators work but I don't get why they work and feel that if there was a interview question that would require using Bitwise operators I would not be able to come up with this strategy.

Comment: @user258365: sorry for the cryptic shortcut: `(i ^ len) & 1` has the value `1` if `i` and `len` have different parities.  It could be written more explicitly as `(i & 1) != (len & 1)`, but compilers did not used to generate efficient code for the latter.  Along the same lines, `(i & len) & 1` tests whether `i` and `len` are both even and `!(i | len) & 1)` tests if they are both odd...

Comment: @user258365: Regarding how I developed such bitwise thinking, I have always had a pathological inclination for early optimisation and code concision, which was useful back in the late '70s and early '80s to pack features into a few kilobytes of code, sometimes even less than a kilobyte. Writing and mostly reading a lot of assembly code from disassembly listings or hex dumps helps develop a sense of how stuff works at the bit level.  The ability to read and understand this stuff is actually more important than the skill to write these obscure expressions. Unless you want to master code golfing.

Answer (score 0):

The basic logic of adding the commas is to first copy the sign character if it exists to the second array and then remove it from the original number array. Then if the number of digits in the Exponent part is odd then 1 digit is copied to the second array and removed to make the length even. then for every odd value of the index 'i' a comma is added.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *convertToInrFormat(char *lp_number, int lv_l)
{
    char *lp_fnumber = '\0';
    char *lp_p = '\0';
    int lv_index = 0;
    int lv_nsize = 0;
    int lv_zerocount = 0;
    int sign_count = 0;
    int expo_count = 0;
    int lv_i = 0;
    int lv_j = 0;

    if (lp_number[0] == '-') // The 0th position of the char array is checked for negative sign, if found sign_count is incremented.
    {
        sign_count++;
    }

    lv_zerocount = strspn(lp_number + sign_count, "0"); // the no. of Leading Zeros is calculated ignoring the negative sign if present.

    if (lp_number[sign_count + lv_zerocount] == '.') //if the exponent part consists of only 0's then the zerocount is reduced by 1 to leave behind 1 zero in the exponent part.
    {
        lv_zerocount = lv_zerocount - 1;
    }

    if (lv_zerocount > 0) //the zeros are removed by being overwritten
    {
        memmove(lp_number + sign_count, lp_number + lv_zerocount + sign_count, strlen(lp_number));
    }

    while (lp_number[sign_count] != '.' && lp_number[sign_count] != '\0') //the count of remaining exponents is taken
    {
        expo_count++;
        sign_count++;
    }

    lv_l = strlen(lp_number); // New string length

    if (expo_count > 3) //inserting the commas
    {
        lv_nsize = lv_l + (expo_count / 2 - 1) + 1;
        lp_fnumber = (char *)malloc(lv_nsize);

        if (lp_fnumber != NULL)
        {
            if (lp_number[0] == '-')
            {
                lp_fnumber[0] = lp_number[0];
                lv_j++;
                memmove(lp_number, lp_number + 1, strlen(lp_number));
                lv_l--;

                if (expo_count % 2 != 0)
                {
                    lp_fnumber[1] = lp_number[0];
                    lv_j++;
                    memmove(lp_number, lp_number + 1, strlen(lp_number));
                    expo_count--;
                }
            }
            else if (expo_count % 2 != 0)
            {
                lp_fnumber[0] = lp_number[0];
                lv_j = lv_j + 1;
                memmove(lp_number, lp_number + 1, strlen(lp_number));
                expo_count--;
            }

            lp_p = strchr(lp_number, '.');
            if (lp_p != NULL)
            {
                lv_index = lp_p - lp_number;
            }

            while (lv_i < expo_count)
            {
                lp_fnumber[lv_j++] = lp_number[lv_i++];

                if (lv_i + 2 < expo_count && lv_i % 2 != 0) //Alt logic:((lv_i ^ lv_l) & 1) here for every odd value of i index a comma is added.
                    lp_fnumber[lv_j++] = ',';
            }
            if (lv_index != 0)
            {
                while (lp_number[lv_index] != '\0')
                {
                    lp_fnumber[lv_j++] = lp_number[lv_index++];
                }
            }
            lp_fnumber[lv_j] = '\0';
        }
        return lp_fnumber;
    }
    else
    {
        return lp_number;
    }
}

   int main()
{
    char lp_number[255];
    int lv_l;
    char *formated_number;
    printf("Enter the lp_number\n");
    fgets(lp_number, 255, stdin);
    lv_l = strlen(lp_number);
    formated_number = convertToInrFormat(lp_number, lv_l);
    puts(formated_number);
}
```

Comment: Make any changes as an edit to your question. Do not post a separate answer.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje [Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: This function leaks memory with a potential `mantissa = malloc()`, yet no matching `free()`.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.